# Will Cisco IOS routers pass all traffic by default without ACLs?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, acl

I have a 1941 out of the box. I can't find documentation on this anywhere, but I'm wondering if the router will pass all traffic by default without adding any ACLs?

I'm curious if the implicit deny all is only triggered after you add your first ACL, or is it always there to begin with?

Will the 1941 pass traffic without adding ACLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there no ACL's added on interface, then all traffic will be passed. Same will be if you're create empty ACL and assign it to interface. Each ACL have explicit deny in the end of list, but it works only if ACL have at least one rule.